# Objective-C NSNumber - Undeclared identifier?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, nsnumber

I write:

```
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] + 5];
```

Why do I get this warning that says aNumber is undeclared on the line of bNumber?

EDIT:

These codes:

```
    NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
    NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] + 5];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)bNumber];
```

is used in the method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```

On the aNumber line, I get the complaint "Expected expression" and on the bNumber line, I get "Unknown receiver 'aNumber'; did you mean NSNumber"?
Why is that so?

EDIT 2:

```
switch (component){ 
    case 0: 
        NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]; 
        NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] + 5]; 
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)bNumber]; 
        break; 
    case 1: 
        //....
    break; 
    case 2: 
        //....
    break; 
}
```

I suspect that I cannot declare anything inside switch statements?

Comment: This compiles perfectly for me.

Comment: Me too, I've no issue with this code

Comment: perfectly printing me the result "bNumber 5"

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using and what are the compiler settings?

Comment: @middaparka I use Version 4.4.1.

Comment: Could you show the whole method, or at least the line before?

Comment: @vaderkvam added an edit for this.

Comment: That's it. You cannot declare a variable within a switch/case. Don't ask me why. But I have had similar issues and solved them as you see in my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Expected expression" errors are very ofthen caused by some syntax flaws in the line(s) before. Have a look at the lines above the aNumber line. Or share those lines with us if you cannot identify the error.

Edit: Thanks for the edit. In this case the answer is that you cannot declare variables within a switch/case statement. It should work this way:

```
NSNumber *aNumber;
NSNumber *bNumber;
switch (component){ 
    case 0: 
        aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]; 
        bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] + 5]; 
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)bNumber]; 
        break; 
    case 1: 
        //....
    break; 
    case 2: 
        //....
    break; 
}
```

If you really need to declare them within the scope of the case-branch then you would have to change your program from switch/case to if clauses. Within the body of an if clause you can easily declare local variables.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this issue! :)

Comment: Note that there is still an error in the `stringWithFormat` line. Casting `NSNumber *bNumber` to `long` will not give the expected result. You have to use `[bNumber longValue]` (as in Mohd Kalimullah Sheikh's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
NSLog(@"Value : %@",[self convert]);

-(NSString*)convert
{
    NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
    NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] + 5];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)([bNumber longValue])];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You did not use exactly same code as you changed from 0 to 10 in aNumber-line and it is called "getting no error" :P

Comment: no i am also checking after putting 0 value in iPhone application and mac Application after that I am saying

Comment: would you like to share your screen shot

Comment: i think i am trying to solve the problem and want to know exact problem

Comment: and this is main objective of stack overflow site.